# REACT ERROR: en el archivo chokidar.js, no me deja compilar mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compilador

Realicé un proyecto con npx create-react-app , estaba trabajando en el y de repente salió el siguiente error:

```
    Failed to compile
./node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\React projects\TheFilmApp\thefilmapp\node_modules\watchpack\lib\chokidar.js: 'return' outside of function (4:1)

  2 | try {
  3 |   module.exports = require("chokidar");
> 4 |   return;
    |   ^
  5 | } catch(e) {
  6 |   v3Err = e;
  7 | }
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Si alguno me ayuda a solucionarlo , se lo agradeceré ya que no me deja continuar con mi proyecto

Comment: Gracias , por responder pero no es el mismo error, ya estuve buscando soluciones en stackeroverflow y no logré encontrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si ya lo pudiste resolver, en mi caso hice un import accidentalmente y perdí horas buscando que lo ocasionaba, te recomiendo revisar si tienes algún plugin de webpack importado accidentalmente, en mi caso fue:

```
import { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin } from "webpack";
```

Lei en otro post que tambien podian ser otros, en el caso que encontré fue:

```
import { IgnorePlugin } from 'webpack';
```

Te dejo el enlace al post que conseguí esa información
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448436/react-js-syntaxerror-occurs-in-node-modules-webpack-chokidar-js-return-outside

Espero que te sea de ayuda!!